# Filter ListView with SearchView

Tags: java, android, search

Ok, so, I have the following listview adapter:

**ListViewAdapter.java**

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends CursorAdapter{
    public ListViewAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, cursor, 0);
    }


    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        return LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.listitem, parent, false);
    }


    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        // Find fields to populate in inflated template
        Button btnList = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnList);
        // Populate fields with cursor
       btnList.setText(cursor.getString(0));

    }
}
```

And here is the XML I am inflating:

**listitem.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/btnList"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/listview_item"
android:focusable="false"
android:clickable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>
```

And then I am using it here to give the ListView the contents of the cursor:

**MainActivity.java**

```
ListViewAdapter lvAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, cursor);
listView.setAdapter(lvAdapter);
```

Now, how would one use a SearchView to filter the ListView everytime I change the searchView text? (Like onTextChange or something)?

I've come up with this so far:

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            todoAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return true;
        }
});
```

But it doesn't do anything... If you need any more information feel free to ask :)

**My Layout:**
[image: My current Layout.]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use this
THis is part from my project I'm currently working on
Here is two arraylists one showProjectList and another projectlist
projectlist contains the actual data what you want to filter and showprojectlist contains the data from projectlist which is filtered and which is to be shown.

```
searchview.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    if (searchview.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                        showProjectList = projectList;
                        ProjectAdapter adapter = new ProjectAdapter(getInstance(), showProjectList);
                        projectListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                        noOfProjectFoundTextView.setText(showProjectList.size() + "");
                        noProjectFoundLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    } else {
                        showProjectList = new ArrayList<ProjectModel>();
                        showProjectList.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < projectList.size(); i++) {
                            if (projectList.get(i).getProjectName()
                                    .toString()
                                    .toLowerCase()
                                    .startsWith(
                                            searchview.getText().toString().toLowerCase()) || projectList.get(i).getProjectName()
                                    .toString()
                                    .toLowerCase()
                                    .contains(
                                            searchview.getText().toString().toLowerCase())) {

                                ProjectModel mData = new ProjectModel();
                                mData.projectId = projectList.get(i).getProjectId();
                                mData.itemCount = projectList.get(i).getItemCount();
                                mData.projectName = projectList.get(i).getProjectName();
                                mData.createdDate = projectList.get(i).createdDate;
                                mData.lInfoList = projectList.get(i).getlInfoList();

                                showProjectList.add(mData);


                            }
                        }

                        ProjectAdapter adapter = new ProjectAdapter(getInstance(), showProjectList);
                        projectListView.setAdapter(adapter);

                    }

                }
            });//search ended
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright lets say you have an arraylist named mainArrayList. So, now you you want to search something from it.
Create a method(lets say mySearch(String str)) and pass the search string as its parameter. Take a new arraylist declared globally, loop through your mainArrayList & check whether the maiArrayList items contains the string, if your mainArrayList contins the string then add the item in your new arraylist and use the new arraylist in your listView.

also, add your newly implemented method mySearch(String str) inside

```
   @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) 
    { mySearch(newText);

        return true;
    }
```